# Function that returns a function

Tags: objective-c, function, lambda, anonymous-function, objective-c-blocks

How to assign and subsequently call a function that returns a function to a local variable in Objective-C?

UPDATE:

I've come up with the following but it's still not right I'm afraid:

```
(void (^)()) (^loadedCallback) () = (void (^)()) ^(){
    @synchronized (synchronizer) {
        semaphore++;
    }
      return Block_copy(^{
          @synchronized (synchronizer) {
              semaphore--;
              if (semaphore == 0) {
                  onAllLoaded();
              }
          }
      }); };
```

Comment: You might want to look into `dispatch_semaphore`s, which provide a fast, lockless interface to semaphores.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to understand the [function pointer declaration syntax](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi). It's the same for blocks, except that it's a `^` instead of a `*`.

Then, you need to create a block and return a *copy* of it, and assign that to a correctly-declared variable.

```
typedef NSArray* (^my_block_type_t)(int, float);

my_block_type_t createBlock()
{
    my_block_type_t block = ^(int a, float b)
    {
        return [NSArray array];
    };
    return Block_copy(block);
}

/* snip */
my_block_type_t theBlock = createBlock();
theBlock();
Block_release(theBlock);
```

---

**EDIT** to address OP's edit: `typedef`s are typically used to make code easier to read. In the case of blocks and function pointers, it also makes it easier to write. There is a built-in `typedef` (`dispatch_block_t`) for blocks that accept no arguments and return `void`; you should use it. You should also make as many typedefs as you need to avoid having to use the ugly declaration syntax function pointers otherwise force onto your code.

```
typedef dispatch_block_t (^block_creator_t)();

block_creator_t loadedCallback = ^{
    @synchronized (synchronizer)
    {
        semaphore++;
    }

    dispatch_block_t result = ^{
        @synchronized (synchronizer)
        {
            semaphore--;
            if (semaphore == 0)
                onAllLoaded();
        }
    };

    return Block_copy(result);
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Block_copy` and `Block_release` be used? I know blocks have an isa pointer and can be messaged it just seems like thats an implementation detail.

Comment: @Joe, that's mostly a (bad?) habit on my end. I'll change that to Block_copy/Block_release.